# How to convert json array to xml array for post request?

Tags: arrays, json, xml

I have following post data for a JSON request which is working fine.

> "customer"=>{"subdomain"=>"Test", "firstname"=>"john",
>   "lastname"=>"doe", "email"=>"john.doe@example.com",
>   "company"=>"Sample", "default_language"=>"en",
>   "active_modules"=>["cmdb", "evm", "itil"]}

I have also enabled XML for my server, so want to respond to XML post requests too. I tried to convert above JSON data to XML but it's not as expected.

```
<customer>
   <active_modules>
      <element>cmdb</element>
      <element>evm</element>
      <element>itil</element>
   </active_modules>
   <company>Sample</company>
   <default_language>en</default_language>
   <email>john.doe@example.com</email>
   <firstname>john</firstname>
   <lastname>doe</lastname>
   <subdomain>Test</subdomain>
</customer>
```

Problem is with array element. How can I convert this array element to pass exactly same data as JSON requests to server?

Answer (score 0):

For an array, you need to pass same node multiple times.

```
<customer>
   <active_modules>cmdb</active_modules>
   <active_modules>evm</active_modules>
   <active_modules>itil</active_modules>
   <company>Sample</company>
   <default_language>en</default_language>
   <email>john.doe@example.com</email>
   <firstname>john</firstname>
   <lastname>doe</lastname>
   <subdomain>Test</subdomain>
</customer>
```